# What constitutes as a restrictive or nonrestrictive?

Tags: commas, dependent-clause, non-restrictive

I'm struggling with trying to figure out whether or not this sentence needs a comma before "only."

"He stopped running, only to grab a log from a stack of firewood and launch it at me."

On one hand, the comma and natural pause sounds more natural to me but I'm not sure if  "only to grab a log from a stack of firewood and launch it at me" constitutes as restrictive? It is also a dependent clause and therefore wouldn't need the comma after "only," right?

I'm very unsure of what to do here.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to say that the only reason he stopped running was to to grab a log ...?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what the author intended.

Comment: In that case the comma is not necessary. The "grab" clause is an adjunct of purpose that is tightly integrated into the structure of the matrix clause so there is no reason to set it off with a comma. Compare also "He only stopped running (in order) to grab a log from a stack of firewood and launch it at me.”

Answer (score 1):

He stopped A, only to B. This is a reasonably common construction in narratives. It does not mean he stopped A for the sole purpose of doing B. It means that he stopped A which was bad in some way, and then began doing B which was also bad.

> He stopped running (so I thought I was safe), only to grab a log etc (when I found I wasn't safe).

> The tenant in the room above stopped dragging furniture (which was keeping me awake) only to start dancing (which was just as noisy).

The reader is led to think briefly that a problem is solved, but then discovers that a new problem has arisen.

If the comma is left out it would mean that the only reason for stopping A was to B.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant usages.

The first has a comma before *only*:

> Only = used to show what is the single or main reason why something mentioned in the first part of the sentence cannot be performed or is not completely true:
>
> I'd invite Frances to the party, only (= but I will not because) I don't want her husband to come.
>
> I'd call him myself, only (= but I cannot because) I'm at work all day.
>
> I'd be happy to do it for you, only (= but) don't expect it to be done before next week.

And the second has no preceding comma:

> Only = used to refer to something that happens almost immediately after something else:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only)
>
> People were leaving and I'd only just arrived.
>
> We'd only just set off when the car broke down

I leave it to you to decide which applies to your text.

Comment: The OP has already confirmed the intended meaning in comments. The clause is a purpose adjunct with the focusing adverb modifying the infinitival clause.

Comment: @BillJ No doubt that is useful grammatical formalism. Your comment about "confirms" leads us into a discussion of the meaning of "believe". Whether in the context of the PO's comment it means an assertion or a conjecture is an open question. I took it to be the second because the answer covers both possibilities, whereas to assume only the first is to risk the answer's being incomplete..